# Apache Camel ftp component sortBy file:modified

Tags: sorting, grails, apache-camel

Using Apache Camel plugin for Grails.  Consuming ftp endpoint and wish to process files via modified date.  This is not working as expected using "...&sortBy=file:modified" url param.  It ignores the date and sorts by the filename.  I've tried several versions like "reverse:file:modified" and "date:file:yyyyMMddmmssSSS".  Platform is Grails 2.3.5 running on Linux.

TIA,
Eric

Answer (score 5):

"sortBy=file:modified;file:name" works fine if you do not use "maxMessagesPerPoll=1".  ;)

Thanks.

Comment: You can still have maxMessagesPerPoll set as long as you have eagerMaxMessagesPerPoll = false. The false option would scan all files, and then perform sorting. Setting this option to false allows for sorting all files first, and then limit the poll. Mind that this requires a higher memory usage as all file details are in memory to perform the sorting. http://camel.apache.org/file2.html

Answer (score 4):

If you want to sort by oldest modified file, then you need to use `sortBy=file:modified`

If you want to sort by last modified file, then you need to use `sortBy=reverse:file:modified`